# How to use fillna() with the mean of multiple rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have `dataframe` to multiple countries and there is `NaN` values that I want to fill with the mean of each row:

```
    country 1616    1617    1618    1619    1620    1621    1622    1623    1624    
0   Afghanistan NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 17.8
1   Albania NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 23.3
2   Algeria NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 27.6 NaN NaN 29.6
3   Angola  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaNNaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 
4   Argentina   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 23.3
```

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
age_marriage.fillna(age_marriage.mean(axis=1),inplace=True)
```

Comment: What would the mean be of rows with `NaN` values?

Comment: 0      17.800000
1      21.960000
2      22.700000
3      19.400000

Comment: `df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.mean()), axis=1)`

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to do this rather than just compute the mean in a new column?  Naively it seems like you're making the data less useful by doing this.

Comment: i need to compare between 3 DF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Sam's comment after handling the `string`/`float` situation.

One way would be to [**`set_index()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to `country`, convert [**`astype(float)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), then [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) along rows to fill by the mean:

```py
df = df.set_index('country').astype(float)
df = df.apply(lambda row: row.fillna(row.mean()), axis=1)

# country     1616  1617  1618  1619  1620  1621  1622  1623  1624  1625  1626  1627  1628  1629  1630  1631
# Afghanistan 17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8  17.8
# Albania     23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3
# Algeria     28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  28.6  27.6  28.6  28.6  29.6  28.6
# Angola       NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
# Argentina   23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3  23.3
# ...
```